# test if shapefile falls inside rectangle in R

Tags: r, intersection, rectangles, shapefile

That seems easy, but I couldn't find it. How do I test if at least part of a shapefile is inside a rectangle in R? I know I could use gIntersects from rgeos package, but for this I would need a sp object instead of a simple rectangle. Since I'm doing it lots of times, it would be more time consuming. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's really not that hard to coerce / convert a rectangle to a `sp` shape.  Certainly easier than reinventing the code in the packages which do the overlap tests!

Comment: What if your rectangle is completely inside a hole inside your feature? Does that count as intersection or not?

Comment: Not in my case @Spacedman. The polygons are species distributions, and I want to see if the species occurr in some squares of a grid.

Comment: You mean your polygons don't have holes and so the situation can't arise?

Comment: No, I mean they may have holes, and if a square falls inside a hole, gIntersects will return false (right?) and that's what I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your rectangle points, note the first and last point match up:

```
rect.1 <- data.frame(long=c(-117,-117,-114,-114,-117),lat=c(35,40,40,35,35))
```

Now create spatial polygons object. You only need five levels of nested parens:

```
rectS = SpatialPolygons(list(
                         Polygons(list(
                           Polygon(coords=rect.1)
                         ),ID=1)),
                         proj4string=proj4string(cali))
```

where `cali` is my SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of California, it has a lat-long projection and you have to set the rectangle to be the same.

Now you can:

```
gIntersects(rectS,cali)
## [1] TRUE
```

Repeat over rectangles.

Oh, and of course four points in lat-long coordinates don't make a "rectangle" in the sense we learned at school because the earth isn't flat...

Comment: Other question: any special reason to use <- in the first line and = in the second? Don't quite get the difference between those operators yet.

Comment: @Rodrigo no, he should have used `<-` for consistency but simple assignments like these work either way.

Comment: The "<-" came from a cut n paste from another answer, the "=" was my original typing!